# Sort elements with GreenSock

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-ui-sortable, gsap

I'm looking for solution How to sort DOM elements with GreenSock animatio library. 
Example something like this http://codepen.io/osublake/pen/RNLdpz
but I want to sort objects right after add the new tile function.
So new element will be appears directly in right position.

## Sortable Grid Using GreenSock Draggable

```
<div class="layout">
  <label><input id="mixed" name="layout" type="radio" value="mixed" checked=""/> Mixed Tile Size</label>
  <label><input id="fixed" name="layout" type="radio" value="fixed"/> Fixed Tile Size</label>
  <label><input id="column" name="layout" type="radio" value="column"/> Single Column</label>
</div>
<button id="add">ADD TILE</button>
<div id="list"></div>

var rowSize   = 100;
var colSize   = 100;
var gutter    = 7;     // Spacing between tiles
var numTiles  = 25;    // Number of tiles to initially populate the grid with
var fixedSize = false; // When true, each tile's colspan will be fixed to 1
var oneColumn = false; // When true, grid will only have 1 column and tiles have fixed colspan of 1
var threshold = "50%"; // This is amount of overlap between tiles needed to detect a collision

var $add  = $("#add");
var $list = $("#list");
var $mode = $("input[name='layout']");

// Live node list of tiles
var tiles  = $list[0].getElementsByClassName("tile");
var label  = 1;
var zIndex = 1000;

var startWidth  = "100%";
var startSize   = colSize;
var singleWidth = colSize * 3;

var colCount   = null;
var rowCount   = null;
var gutterStep = null;

var shadow1 = "0 1px 3px  0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)";
var shadow2 = "0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";

$(window).resize(resize);
$add.click(createTile);
$mode.change(init);

init();

// ========================================================================
//  INIT
// ========================================================================
function init() {

  var width = startWidth;

  // This value is defined when this function 
  // is fired by a radio button change event
  switch (this.value) {

    case "mixed":
      fixedSize = false;
      oneColumn = false;
      colSize   = startSize;
      break;

    case "fixed":
      fixedSize = true;
      oneColumn = false;
      colSize   = startSize;
      break;

    case "column":
      fixedSize = false;
      oneColumn = true;
      width     = singleWidth;
      colSize   = singleWidth;
      break;
  }

  $(".tile").remove();

  TweenLite.to($list, 0.2, { width: width });
  TweenLite.delayedCall(0.25, populateBoard);

  function populateBoard() {

    label = 1;
    resize();

    for (var i = 0; i < numTiles; i++) {
      createTile();
    }
  }
}


// ========================================================================
//  RESIZE
// ========================================================================
function resize() {

  colCount   = oneColumn ? 1 : Math.floor($list.outerWidth() / (colSize + gutter));
  gutterStep = colCount == 1 ? gutter : (gutter * (colCount - 1) / colCount);
  rowCount   = 0;

  layoutInvalidated();
}


// ========================================================================
//  CHANGE POSITION
// ========================================================================
function changePosition(from, to, rowToUpdate) {

  var $tiles = $(".tile");
  var insert = from > to ? "insertBefore" : "insertAfter";

  // Change DOM positions
  $tiles.eq(from)[insert]($tiles.eq(to));

  layoutInvalidated(rowToUpdate);
}

// ========================================================================
//  CREATE TILE
// ========================================================================
function createTile() {

  var colspan = fixedSize || oneColumn ? 1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  var element = $("<div></div>").addClass("tile").html(label++);
  var lastX   = 0;

  Draggable.create(element, {
    onDrag      : onDrag,
    onPress     : onPress,
    onRelease   : onRelease,
    zIndexBoost : false
  });

  // NOTE: Leave rowspan set to 1 because this demo 
  // doesn't calculate different row heights
  var tile = {
    col        : null,
    colspan    : colspan,
    height     : 0,
    inBounds   : true,
    index      : null,
    isDragging : false,
    lastIndex  : null,
    newTile    : true,
    positioned : false,
    row        : null,
    rowspan    : 1, 
    width      : 0,
    x          : 0,
    y          : 0
  };

  // Add tile properties to our element for quick lookup
  element[0].tile = tile;

  $list.append(element);
  layoutInvalidated();

  function onPress() {

    lastX = this.x;
    tile.isDragging = true;
    tile.lastIndex  = tile.index;

    TweenLite.to(element, 0.2, {
      autoAlpha : 0.75,
      boxShadow : shadow2,
      scale     : 0.95,
      zIndex    : "+=1000"
    });
  }

  function onDrag() {

    // Move to end of list if not in bounds
    if (!this.hitTest($list, 0)) {
      tile.inBounds = false;
      changePosition(tile.index, tiles.length - 1);
      return;
    }

    tile.inBounds = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {

      // Row to update is used for a partial layout update
      // Shift left/right checks if the tile is being dragged 
      // towards the the tile it is testing
      var testTile    = tiles[i].tile;
      var onSameRow   = (tile.row === testTile.row);
      var rowToUpdate = onSameRow ? tile.row : -1;
      var shiftLeft   = onSameRow ? (this.x < lastX && tile.index > i) : true;
      var shiftRight  = onSameRow ? (this.x > lastX && tile.index < i) : true;
      var validMove   = (testTile.positioned && (shiftLeft || shiftRight));

      if (this.hitTest(tiles[i], threshold) && validMove) {
        changePosition(tile.index, i, rowToUpdate);
        break;
      }
    }

    lastX = this.x;
  }

  function onRelease() {

    // Move tile back to last position if released out of bounds
    this.hitTest($list, 0)
      ? layoutInvalidated()
      : changePosition(tile.index, tile.lastIndex);

    TweenLite.to(element, 0.2, {
      autoAlpha : 1,
      boxShadow: shadow1,
      scale     : 1,
      x         : tile.x,
      y         : tile.y,
      zIndex    : ++zIndex
    });

    tile.isDragging = false;
  }
}

// ========================================================================
//  LAYOUT INVALIDATED
// ========================================================================
function layoutInvalidated(rowToUpdate) {

  var timeline = new TimelineMax();
  var partialLayout = (rowToUpdate > -1);

  var height = 0;
  var col    = 0;
  var row    = 0;
  var time   = 0.35;

  $(".tile").each(function(index, element) {

    var tile    = this.tile;
    var oldRow  = tile.row;
    var oldCol  = tile.col;
    var newTile = tile.newTile;

    // PARTIAL LAYOUT: This condition can only occur while a tile is being 
    // dragged. The purpose of this is to only swap positions within a row, 
    // which will prevent a tile from jumping to another row if a space
    // is available. Without this, a large tile in column 0 may appear 
    // to be stuck if hit by a smaller tile, and if there is space in the 
    // row above for the smaller tile. When the user stops dragging the 
    // tile, a full layout update will happen, allowing tiles to move to
    // available spaces in rows above them.
    if (partialLayout) {
      row = tile.row;
      if (tile.row !== rowToUpdate) return;
    }

    // Update trackers when colCount is exceeded 
    if (col + tile.colspan > colCount) {
      col = 0; row++;
    }

    $.extend(tile, {
      col    : col,
      row    : row,
      index  : index,
      x      : col * gutterStep + (col * colSize),
      y      : row * gutterStep + (row * rowSize),
      width  : tile.colspan * colSize + ((tile.colspan - 1) * gutterStep),
      height : tile.rowspan * rowSize
    });

    col += tile.colspan;

    // If the tile being dragged is in bounds, set a new
    // last index in case it goes out of bounds
    if (tile.isDragging && tile.inBounds) {
      tile.lastIndex = index;
    }

    if (newTile) {

      // Clear the new tile flag
      tile.newTile = false;

      var from = {
        autoAlpha : 0,
        boxShadow : shadow1,
        height    : tile.height,
        scale     : 0,
        width     : tile.width
      };

      var to = {
        autoAlpha : 1,
        scale     : 1,
        zIndex    : zIndex
      }

      timeline.fromTo(element, time, from, to, "reflow");
    }

    // Don't animate the tile that is being dragged and
    // only animate the tiles that have changes
    if (!tile.isDragging && (oldRow !== tile.row || oldCol !== tile.col)) {

      var duration = newTile ? 0 : time;

      // Boost the z-index for tiles that will travel over 
      // another tile due to a row change
      if (oldRow !== tile.row) {
        timeline.set(element, { zIndex: ++zIndex }, "reflow");
      }

      timeline.to(element, duration, {
        x : tile.x,
        y : tile.y,
        onComplete : function() { tile.positioned = true; },
        onStart    : function() { tile.positioned = false; }
      }, "reflow");
    }
  });

  // If the row count has changed, change the height of the container
  if (row !== rowCount) {
    rowCount = row;
    height   = rowCount * gutterStep + (++row * rowSize);
    timeline.to($list, 0.2, { height: height }, "reflow");
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean "So new element will be appears directly in right position"? Could you elaborate on what the desired effect is, and what problem you're having right now?

Comment: Hi Marco, I mean if you will have sorted collection of objects 0..99. New element with number 22 will appears on the 22th place of array not last or first one.